# How to know if a string character divisible by numbers or not in C language

Tags: c, string

So here is the problem:

- Input a string contains of numbers from 0 to 9 (maximum length is 15)
- If the left most character divisible by 3, remove it from the string
- If the right most character divisible by 3, remove it from the string
- If the string does not match the above two conditions, and if the summary of the left most character and the right most character is divisible by 3, remove them from the string.
- Keep doing so until the string is NULL or not meet the above conditions.
  Example: input: "312248" ---> output: 2.
  input: "366936363" ---> output: ""
  So here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

char* truncateString(char* s)
{
  char *p = &s[0];
  int n = strlen(s);
  p = calloc(n,sizeof(char));
  int flag = 1;
do{
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
      {
        if ((s[0]-'0') % 3 == 0)
            {
              for(int j = 0; j < strlen(s); j++)
                  {
                    s[j] = s[j+1];
                  }
              p = realloc(p, (strlen(s)-1)*sizeof(char));
            }
        else if ((s[strlen(s)-1]-'0') % 3 == 0)
            {
              p = realloc(p, (strlen(s)-1)*sizeof(char));
            }
        else if (((s[strlen(s)-1]-'0')+(s[0]-'0')) % 3 == 0)
            {
              for(int j = 0; j < (strlen(s)-1); j++)
                  {
                    s[j] = s[j+1];
                    p = realloc(p, (strlen(s)-2)*sizeof(char));
                  }
            }
        else
            {
              flag = 0;
            }
      }
    } while (strlen(s) != 0 || flag != 0);
    free(p);
return s;
}

int main()
{
  char s[100];
  gets(s);
  printf("Result:%s", truncateString(s));
getch();
return 0;
}
```

I honestly do not know how to check if the character is divisible by 3 or not, so the code is not running.

Comment: It does not return the result, i dont know why

Comment: i got it, so i cannot use else if in this case  but i  have to use if

Comment: You point p at s and then immediately point it to somewhere else allocated by calloc and then you modify p a bunch without ever putting anything in it and then free it and then finally return an unmodified s.  You don't need all the reallocs and all that.  The question is - did you want to return a modified s or return an allocated string containing the data without modifying s?

Comment: All those calls to `strlen(s)` - which in this case doesn't change. Just put it in a vraiable already !

Comment: @QuanLeAnh  I don't think the else is the problem - because you are in a loop if you don't catch it on this iteration you will catch it on the next - I think it will work with the else.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I suspect you are [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68264088/how-to-know-if-a-string-character-divisible-by-numbers-or-not-in-c-language/68269601#comment120647018_68264088).  It does lead to an interesting (and maybe speedier) architecture, say if one does not proceed per the coding goals, yet still matches the overall functionality.  A downside is maintenance: If the coding goals change a bit, how clear is it to amend the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having troubles with reallocation too. Try this, it may make things easier

```
char* truncateString(char* s)
{

  int n = strlen(s);
  int flag = 1;
while (strlen(s) != 0 && flag != 0){
        if ((s[0]-'0') % 3 == 0)
          s++;

        else if ((s[strlen(s)-1]-'0') % 3 == 0)
            s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';
        else if (((s[strlen(s)-1]-'0')+(s[0]-'0')) % 3 == 0)
        {
          s++;
          s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';
        }
        else
            flag = 0;
    }

return s;
}
```

Quick explanation: when you declare `s++` you are preciselly removing the first element of the array, and using  `s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0'` removes the last element.

**EDIT**:

Another solution here, that will work faster. Instead of calling `s[strlen(s)-1]` each time, you can just keep track of the initial `n=strlen(s);` Also, removed the `-'0'`, because `ASCII` codes for numbers start in `48`, so they are in the right position for checking divisibility by 3. Thanks to `@chux-ReinstateMonica`. Here is the code:

```
char* truncateString(char* s)
    {

      int n = strlen(s);
      int flag = 1;
    while (n != 0 && flag != 0){
            if ((s[0]) % 3 == 0){
              s++;
              n--;
            }
            else if ((s[n-1]) % 3 == 0)
                s[--n] = '\0';
            else if (((s[n-1])+(s[0])) % 3 == 0)
            {
              s++;
              n--;
              s[--n] = '\0';
            }
            else
                flag = 0;
        }
    return s;
    }
```

Comment: Code without explanation of the problems or how they were fixed is not a good answer.

Comment: I wrote the explanation at the end

Comment: wow thank you ! I finally get better understanding about this!

Comment: robbinc91, Note: `s++;  s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';` has a performance weakness.   This code  runs down the string to find its length., making this solution O(n*n).  A serious impact with large `n`.  Keeping track of `n` would save a lot of time.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, you have reason, you can just find the initial length of the string and decrement it in each step instead of calling s[strlen(s)-1], but in the problem specs, the first point says that maximum input will have 15 digits at most, for that reason i did not improve the code. however, I'll fix it and post it too. thanks so much!

Comment: True, 15 is not so bad.

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider a re-write that clearly matches the coding goals to fix functional errors.

`(s[0]-'0') % 3 == 0` is a fine way to test for divisibility as `s[0]-'0'` provides the textual `char` to `int` value.

It is often useful to put the goals in as comments right where they are used.

`strlen()` needs to be called just once.  Update the length as needed.  This avoids repetitive calls to `strlen()`, each costing O(len).

```
char* truncateString(char *s) {
  char *start = s;
  size_t len = strlen(s);

  // Keep doing so until the string is "NULL"
  while (len > 0) {
    char left = s[0] - '0';
    bool left_remove = left % 3 == 0;
    char right = s[len - 1] - '0';
    bool right_remove = right % 3 == 0;
    bool right_differ_from_left = len > 1;

    // If the left most character divisible by 3, remove it from the string
    if (left_remove) {
      s++;
      len--;
    }

    // Only consider the 'right' if the string was more than 1.
    if (right_differ_from_left) {
      // If the right most character divisible by 3, remove it from the string
      if (right_remove) {
        len--;
        s[len] = '\0';
      }

      // If the string does not match the above two conditions,
      // and if the summary of the left most character and
      // the right most character is divisible by 3,
      // remove them from the string.
      if (!left_remove && !right_remove && (left + right) % 3 == 0) {
        s++;
        len -= 2;
        s[len] = '\0';
        left_remove = right_remove = true;
      }
    }

    // Keep doing so until the string is ... not meet the above conditions.
    if (!left_remove && !right_remove) {
      break;
    }
  }

  // Move string to its original beginning.
  return memmove(start, s, len + 1);
}
```

---

If the coding goals are stable, simplifications exists.  Yet notice that this may be faster, it is harder to see it matches the coding goals than the above.

```
char* truncateString2(char *s) {
  char *start = s;
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  size_t len_at_loop_start;
  do {
    len_at_loop_start = len;
    while (len > 0 && (s[0] - '0') % 3 == 0) {
      s++;
      len--;
    }
    while (len > 0 && (s[len-1] - '0') % 3 == 0) {
      len--;
    }
    while (len > 1 && (s[0] - '0' + s[len-1] - '0') % 3 == 0) {
      s++;
      len -= 2;
    }
 } while (len < len_at_loop_start);
  s[len] = '\0';
  return memmove(start, s, len + 1);
}
```